# What is `suite` and `else` in Python's for grammar rule?

Tags: python

Python3 defines for loop as `for_stmt: 'for' exprlist 'in' testlist ':' suite ['else' ':' suite]` in the [grammar book](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html). `suite` is defined as `suite: simple_stmt | NEWLINE INDENT stmt+ DEDENT`.

For me, it's hard to understand how double for loop fits in the grammar description for list comprehension.

There are several smaller questions:

- And what about `else`? I assume it's used for list comprehension.
- Then does a normal for loop can use `else` block?

I'd appreciate if you can come with examples.

Comment: `suite` is either an indented block, or a single statement. `'else'` is literally the string "else".

Comment: Look a few lines furter: `suite: simple_stmt | NEWLINE INDENT stmt+ DEDENT`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see from the other rules of the grammar:

```
suite: simple_stmt | NEWLINE INDENT stmt+ DEDENT
```

`suite` is either a simple statement (in one line), e.g.:

```
for foo in bar: some_statement()
```

or it is a newline, followed by an indented block (which consists of statements).

---

`'else'` is simply the string "else".

I usually read the `else` of a for-loop as "no-break": It is executed after the for-loop is finished, but only if it wasn't exited by `break`. The reason it exists is consistency with `while`, which has an `else` statement, as it's basically just a repeated `if`.

Answer (score 1):

The `else` after a for is executed if the loop finished normally (if it not breaked with `break` keyword)

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html

`suite` is just a indentation level or a single statement

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement), the `else` clause of a `for` loop is executed if the loop ended without having been broken.

See these two examples:

```python
for elem in range(5):
    print(elem)
else:
    print('ended')
```

Here, the `suite` part correspond to `print(elem)`, and the output will be:

```
0
1
2
3
4
ended
```

And second:

```python
for elem in range(5):
    if elem < 3:
        print(elem)
    else:
        break
else:
    print('ended')
```

Here, the `suite` part correspond to `if elem < 3: print(elem) else: break`,
and the output will be:

```
0
1
2
```